# Adding a layer to PDF containing layers with PdfStamper flattens existing layers

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I create PDF files for print containing a non-printable background layer of the stationery, so it will look the same printed and on screen.

[image]

Example to be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9YJlOxlbTanMFBLOFMxUUVCSUU/view?usp=sharing)

Now once the prepared PDF is approved for print, I want to add a barcode containing archive / approval data - again as a layer not printed.

But once I do, all existing layers are gone and only the layer added remains, causing the not-printable background layer to suddenly be printed.

See [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9YJlOxlbTanS0pFdk80SGhXUVk/view?usp=sharing) for my (failed) result

Here's my addBarcode method:

```
public static byte[] addBarcode_OriginalIdea(byte[] src, String barcodeText, String layerName, boolean printable) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);                      
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, bo);
        //Add an additional layer to Page 1
        PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(1);
        Barcode128 barcode = new Barcode128();
        barcode.setCode(barcodeText);
        barcode.setBarHeight(10f);                     
        Image img = barcode.createImageWithBarcode(over, Color.decode("#0c1754"), Color.decode("#0c1754"));
        img.setRotationDegrees(-90f);            
        img.setAbsolutePosition(reader.getPageSize(1).getRight()-img.getHeight()-5,  5);
        PdfLayer barcodeLayer = new PdfLayer(layerName, stamper.getWriter());
        barcodeLayer.setOnPanel(true);
        barcodeLayer.setPrint("Print", printable);
        over.beginLayer(barcodeLayer);
        over.addImage(img);
        over.endLayer();
        //End add layer
        stamper.close();
        bo.close();
        return bo.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new byte[]{};
    }
}
```

Confused. So what did I try next?

1. Remove the code to add the layer - keep the stamper part
   Result: Layers are still there.
2. Print the layers before and after adding the new layer:
   Result: I can see the new layer added, but PdfStamper throws an Exception during close.

Code for that:

```
public static byte[] addBarcode_showLayersBeforeAfter(byte[] src, String barcodeText, String layerName, boolean printable) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);                      
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, bo);
        //List all layers contained in document before
        Map map = stamper.getPdfLayers();
        for(Object me: map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Layer before: " + me);
        }                       

        //Add an additional layer to Page 1
        PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(1);
        Barcode128 barcode = new Barcode128();
        barcode.setCode(barcodeText);
        barcode.setBarHeight(10f);                     
        Image img = barcode.createImageWithBarcode(over, Color.decode("#0c1754"), Color.decode("#0c1754"));
        img.setRotationDegrees(-90f);            
        img.setAbsolutePosition(reader.getPageSize(1).getRight()-img.getHeight()-5,  5);
        PdfLayer barcodeLayer = new PdfLayer(layerName, stamper.getWriter());
        barcodeLayer.setOnPanel(true);
        barcodeLayer.setPrint("Print", printable);
        over.beginLayer(barcodeLayer);
        over.addImage(img);
        over.endLayer();            
        //End add layer

        //List all layers contained in document before
        Map map2 = stamper.getPdfLayers();
        for(Object me: map2.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Layer after: " + me);
        }
        reader.close();
        stamper.close(); // <-- this now throws an Exception!
        bo.close();
        return bo.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new byte[]{};
    }
}
```

This produces this output:

```
Layer before: Footer-2
Layer before: Template-Page-0
Layer before: Template-Page-2
Layer before: Template-Page-1
Layer before: Footer-0
Layer before: Footer-1
Layer after: Footer-2
Layer after: Template-Page-0
Layer after: StackLayer
Layer after: Template-Page-2
Layer after: Template-Page-1
Layer after: Footer-0
Layer after: Footer-1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.fillOCProperties(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper.close(Unknown Source)
    at BarcodeLayer.addBarcode_showLayersBeforeAfter(BarcodeLayer.java:119)
    at BarcodeLayer.main(BarcodeLayer.java:44)
```

I'd really, really hate to have to recreate the whole PDF + barcode at this point just to get the layers straight, does anyone have an idea how to add another non-printable layer in PdfStamper (or some other way) while keeping all existing layers?

Thank you so much!

**EDIT**

With Bruno's advice to move to itext Version 5 it becomes even more strange. Now I can see the layer being added to the PDF. Now the background stays unprinted (as wanted) but the added barcode layer is **always** printed. I used this code to analyse the layers after my adding the barcode:

```
        Map map2 = stamper.getPdfLayers();
        for(Object me: map2.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Layer after: " + me );
            PdfDictionary dict2 = ((PdfLayer)map2.get(me)).getAsDict(PdfName.USAGE);
            if(dict2 != null) {
                PdfDictionary dict = dict2.getAsDict(PdfName.PRINT);
                System.out.println("Subtype" + dict.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE));
                System.out.println("Printable: " + dict.getAsName(PdfName.PRINTSTATE));
            }
        }
```

Resulting in this for the added layer:

```
Printable: /OFF
Layer after: StackLayer
Subtype/Print
```

But still - on hitting print preview the layer is still there. Now I used the just created pdf and listed the layers - and the Print-Attribute is gone:

```
Layer before: StackLayer
Layer before: Template-Page-2
```

So whatever happens seems to happen in closing the PdfStamper - like not properly updating PdfLayers or such. I think I'll have to look into itext source next :-(

Comment: I'm sorry, I was going to look into your problem because I know I can fix this (I fixed a similar problem for a customer a couple of years ago), but then I noticed my name in your stack trace. That means that you are using a version of iText that dates from at least 2009. If you want to avoid frustration (your own frustration as well as mine), please upgrade and [stop using iText versions older than 5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5).

Comment: Hi Bruno thanks for the advice - will do and retest.

Comment: OK, I may not be able to answer a follow-up question immediately. I broke my arm and I can only type with one hand. i shouldn't be working in the next week (but it is hard to follow doctor's orders).

Comment: Get well, Bruno! Changing to iTest 5.5.11 (the company I work has a license) did resolve the exception but not the barcode layer added in stamper is always printed.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: I feel that's a bug in itext pdfstamper - some OCG properties like the Print information seem to not be merged if there are preexisting layers in the PDF to be stamped. To solve my issue I moved the barcode-code into a PageEvent, adding it to the first page in the document, even if that required the whole pdf to be regenerated.

Comment: Please post this as a customer ticket on Jira. I have a broken elbow. I can type with one hand, but answering your question isn't possible without pain. This is typically something we have support engineers for. Please use your support contract for issues like this.